# HttpServletRequest.GetSession returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, wildfly

I have a simple JEE app, which breaks at login. It was working fine before I transferred it from Neon to Mars. Although I changed Server Runtime to WildFly 10.0, it still says that my Server Runtime 10.x is not bound (I changed the runtime both for the Web and EJB project. Anyway, this is my method:

```
public String login(){
        UserDto user = usersBean.validateUser(username, password);
        if(null == user){
            MessageUtils.addErrorMessage("login.error.invalid.credentials");
            return "";
        } else{
            request.getSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_USER", user);
            ******the upper code fails********
            return SUCCESS_LOGIN_REDIRECT;
        }
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
Context Path:/JEEProjectWeb
Servlet Path:/page/login.html
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
bg.JEE.web.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am very new at this and have no clue what may be causing this error. But I've tried putting request.getSession() in a variable and on debugging it returned null, so there should be no problem with the setAttribute function.

Please assist me! Thanks in advance!

Additional info:

Authentication filter:

```
package bg.JEE.web.filter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import bg.JEE.dto.UserDto;

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String PATH_INDEX = "/index.jsp";
    public static final String PATH_LOGIN = "/page/login.html";
    public static final String PATH_LOGOUT = "/page/logout.jsp";

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String requestedPath = httpRequest.getRequestURI().substring(httpRequest.getContextPath().length());

        /*
         * Skip the action with path "index.jsp" - there is no logged user, but
         * the user is redirected to login screen
         */
        if (PATH_INDEX.equals(requestedPath)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response); --row 60
            return;
        }
        /*
         * Skip the action with path "/login.login.html" - there is no logged
         * user, but the user is trying to log in
         */
        if (PATH_LOGIN.equals(requestedPath)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Get logged user from the HttpSession
         */
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        UserDto loggedUser = (UserDto) session.getAttribute("LOGGED_USER");

        /*
         * Redirect to login page if there is no logged user and trying to
         * access protected resource
         */
        if (loggedUser == null) {
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(PATH_LOGIN);
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
            return;
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

And here's the row 60 code from LoginBean:

```
public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you have a custom Servlet Filter in your code (`bg.JEE.web.filter.AuthenticationFilter`). Is that class the one containing the `public String login()` method? If so, what is in the line 60?

Comment: I will post some more code above, but no, Login() method is contained in the class called LoginBean.  bg.JEE.web.filter.AuthenticationFilter contains a check if the user has a session, and as far as I know, it's working, because every time I try to access another page without being logged in, I am redirected to login page. Once again, code is attached in the main question. Thank you!

Comment: Just in! I found out, that @Inject causes the problem. For some reason, when I do "@Inject private HttpServletRequest request" it is null, but when I do "HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext
 .getCurrentInstance()
 .getExternalContext()
  .getRequest();" it works. Does somebody have an idea why is that? From my position it looks like some problem of the container...

Comment: Where are you doing those injection? Unless you're doing JAX-RS Restful Web Service resource, you can't `HttpServletRequest`/`HttpServletResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be several issues.  I can't help with the Eclipse issue but the other error may be part of the problem.  If you use EJBs you need to have a beans.xml.  It can basically be empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

If you have a Maven project, put this in resources/META-INF/beans.xml.  If you're using a different build system this file needs to end up in classes/META-INF/beans.xml in your war file/webapp directory.

The other error - the node identifier message - can be ignored for now.  If you decide to cluster your Wildfly servers then you'll need to update it - see [this link](https://dennis.gesker.com/2016/02/16/wildfly-10-and-wflytx0013/) for more details.

But to come closer to solving your problem, where is "request" passed in?  Can you show a bit more of your code?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I will do that right away. I will be posting more code in a matter of minutes. Stay tuned please!